# Get Custom Field Value From Product Category in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to get a custom field value of a category to display for each product.

I am using the Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) plugin to create a new option called category_attributes within the woocommerce Product categories.

I want to display the value for category_attributes for products that are in this category.

Here is the function that I created.  Currently using "product_cat_22" to display the value from that product category, but it needs to pull in the category id for that product and display the category_attributes field for that category.

```
//Category Listing Hooks
function add_category_info_below_title() {

$custom_field = get_field('category_attributes', 'product_cat_22');

echo '<div class="subCatAtts">' . $custom_field . '</div>';

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_subcategory_title', 'add_category_info_below_title' );
```

Here is the site where this can be viewed - http://mdev4.com/roura/one/

Capacity: 4,000-8,000 LBS is the correct value category_attributes for product category 22.

Comment: few questions .if custom field is directly related to category how you are storing it ? if not you need to create a join query to achieve this .